# GraphQl Django, how to cache at resolver if Type has custom fields added

Tags: django, caching, redis, graphql

scratching my head with this one for the past while but I'm sure I'm just missing something simple. I am using graphene-django and I am trying to also use redis cache.

The issue I am having is as follows.
I have a model AdDetails

```
class AdDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    dealer = models.ForeignKey('DealerLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='dealer')
    county = models.ForeignKey('CountyLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='county')
    vehicle_type = models.ForeignKey('VehicleTypeLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vehicle_type')
    href = models.TextField()
    make = models.ForeignKey('MakeLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='make')
    model = models.ForeignKey('ModelLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='model')
    year = models.ForeignKey('YearLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='year')
    mileage_km = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fuel_type = models.ForeignKey('FuelTypeLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fuel_type')
    transmission = models.ForeignKey('TransmissionLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='transmission', blank=True, null=True)
    engine_size = models.ForeignKey('EngineSizeLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='engine_size', blank=True, null=True)
    colour = models.ForeignKey('ColourLookup', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='colour', blank=True, null=True)
    for_sale_date = models.DateField()
    sold_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ad_details
```

and in schema.py I have added a few fields to it.

```
class AdDetailsType(DjangoObjectType):
    price = graphene.Float()
    previous_price = graphene.Float()
    price_movement = graphene.Float()

    def resolve_price(self, info):
        price_history = self.pricehistory_set.order_by('-date').first()
        if price_history:
            return price_history.price
        return None

    def resolve_previous_price(self, info):
        price_history = self.pricehistory_set.filter(price__gt=0).order_by('date').first()
        if price_history:
            return price_history.price
        return None

    def resolve_price_movement(self, info):
        price = self.pricehistory_set.order_by('-date').first()
        prev_price = self.pricehistory_set.filter(price__gt=0).order_by('date').first()

        if price is not None and prev_price is not None:
            return price.price - prev_price.price
        else:
            return None

    class Meta:
        model = AdDetails
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now further down I have a resolver that I am trying to cache but it only caches I believe the adDetails queryset which does not have the additional price fields. This makes sense as I am querying the model and not the type but I don't know how to turn my AdDetails objects into AdDetailsType objects to be stored into the cache. What I have there works but there is no optimisation as I believe when I call the query again it still has to convert the adDetails to AdDetailTypes so it's going to take a few seconds.

I've tried a few things like passing the AdDetails into AdDetailTypes  with this kind of code but all the fields had 'None' values when I did this.
`r = [AdDetailsType(ad) for ad in result]`
I've also been trying to serialize and do other things but am stumped at this stage.

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    stock_details = graphene.List(AdDetailsType, dealer_id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_stock_details(self, info, dealer_id):
        cache_key = f"stock_details_{dealer_id}"
        cached_result = cache.get(cache_key)
        if cached_result is not None:
            return cached_result

        result = AdDetails.objects.filter(dealer=dealer_id, sold_date__isnull=True).order_by('for_sale_date')
        
        # Cache the query result with a timeout of 10 days
        cache.set(cache_key, result, timeout=864000)

        return result
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, @Robben?

Comment: No, not cleanly anyway. I was using management commands to build my cache and to update it. So for this one rather than have the resolver set the cache I had it being set in the management command itself ignoring graphql. Then I used a Django view to retrieve the cache for this endpoint rather than graphql resolver. Not overly clean but worked for me as the cache only needed to updated daily by running a management command.